# AWS Lambda SSM calls randomly goes in timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I've a lambda deployed on AWS, in a VPC that has internet access via NAT. The deploy is made using [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/).
The lambda uses some [Middy](https://github.com/middyjs/middy) middlewares and fetches some credentials from SSM.

The problem is that the SSM fetch randomly goes in timeout!

Here's the lambda code:

```
/* requirements are omitted */

const authorize = async (_event, _context) => {
  try {
    const ssm = new SSM({
      maxRetries: 6, // lowers a chance to hit service rate limits, default is 3
      retryDelayOptions: { base: 200 }
    })
    const params = {
      Names: ["param1", "param2"],
      WithDecryption: true
    }
    const fetch = () => new Promise(resolve => {
      ssm.getParameters(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) resolve(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     resolve(data);           // successful response
      })
    })
    const res = await fetch()
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(res)
    }
  } catch (_err) {
    console.error(_err)
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: 'error'
    }
  }
}

export default middy(authorize)
  .use(warmup({ waitForEmptyEventLoop: false }))
  .use(doNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop({ runOnError: true }))
  .use(httpSecurityHeaders())
```

Answer (score 2):

The lambda is timing out, because ssm is throttling you with your current configuration (6 retries 200ms) it takes around 26 seconds before your lambda will give up.

You are running here against the [SSM standard throughput limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html).

You can enable [increased throuhgput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-throughput.html) with:

```
aws ssm update-service-setting --setting-id arn:aws:ssm:*region*:*account-id*:servicesetting/ssm/parameter-store/high-throughput-enabled --setting-value true
```

Be aware an [extra cost](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/pricing/) will be incurred for every getParameter call afterwards (0.05$/10.000 requests).

Comment: Hi, thank You for your answer! I would like to ask You two questions, please: 1) How did You managed to calculate 26 seconds starting from 6 retries, 200ms? 2) What is the throughput limit I'm hitting? I can read "Default throughput: 40", so I don't think is this one... ?

Comment: 1) exponential backoff doubles the 200ms with every retry so this ends up in 25,5sec: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=200ms*2%5E7

Comment: 2) did the update-service-setting work?  Then check your usage in cloudwatch or the cost explorer for these specific usages.